# What's the meaning of the expressions "take no issue with" and "starting beef over"?

Tags: word-in-context

> However, when it comes to making a complaint in a restaurant, our national propensity for politeness seems to short circuit. A recent study found that 49% of Brits feel uncomfortable sending food back, and from our own (unofficial) findings, it seems that those who **take no issue** with **starting beef over** an undercooked steak don’t always go about it in the best way.

I'm assuming they are two independent expressions and could be used separately in other texts but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [take issue with](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+issue+with) means to argue with, disagree, or have a problem. The "no" inverts the meaning. A [beef](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beef) is to fight or complain. So, in context, the phrase means something like: British people who are willing to complain about bad food in a restaurant are usually rude.

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot, Ron.